# PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and InputBindings relationship

Tags: wpf, inputbinding

Using `.NET 4.5.1` on `Windows 8.1 Pro`. In my `UserControl` I have grid. I need to preview and handle mouse events in this grid. So I override the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event:

```
    myGrid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown +=
        new MouseButtonEventHandler(myGrid_PreviewLeftButtonDown);
}

private void myGrid_PreviewLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    e.Handled = true; // <-- IMPORTANT!
}
```

My `UserControl` also has a few `InputBindings` that are being registered in the static constructor. E.g.:

```
CommandManager.RegisterClassInputBinding(typeof(MyUserControl),
    new KeyBinding(MyCommands.SelectAll, new KeyGesture(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control)));
```

### `InputBinding` dependent on `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`?!

Now, when I set `e.Handled` to `true` in my `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` handler, my `InputBinding`s stop working! **Why?!** I cannot understand how the mouse handler is linked to my keyboard shortcuts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can come up now is the following: you register input binding to `MyUserControl`, therefore for it to activate this UserControl has to **have focus**. When you make mouse event handled on Grid level, you don't allow this input to go to UserControl. So, no input - no focus, no focus - no command activation.

Let's say we change the code a bit:

```
private void Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, myUC);
}
```

Where `myUC` is our UserControl. But UserControl is not focusable, so we'll add a little focus transfer inside it:

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btn.Focus();
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
}
```

Where `btn` us just some empty Button or whatever focusable element you like. Then it works ok.

So, my take on the problem is: the reason is not in mouse events, it's in **focus**.

Comment: Though I could not get this to work (yet) in my project, the explanation seems reasonable. Indeed, my `UserControl` does not have focus.

Comment: @l33t, I was able to reproduce your problem and fix it with code mentioned, but your code can be more complex indeed. Checking [CommandManager code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/src/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs) also points to focus as a main culpit (`OnCanExecute` handler, for example). But all in all it's more of a guess, so I hope you'll find an exact fix to your problem soon!

Answer (score 1):

PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown is trigged before all other routed events. When you set it e.Handled = true here, you effecticly stop the other events from beeing trigged. This also accounts for other PreviewX routed events, and well the purpose is to stop it. You can add handlers in code though, that will get these events regardless if they are set as handled or not. Very handy for inactivity checks etc.

Like this:

```
AddHandler(MouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(YourHandler), true);


private void YourHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your magic here!
}
```

The last parameter there will cause you to catch MouseUpEvents even though they are handled.

I'm not sure how you can do this with your bindings out of the box, but it might be possible.

Hope it helps some atleast.

Cheers

Stian

Comment: Thanks! But why does the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event affect keyboard events?

Comment: @l33t oh! I read your post a bit fast there. Hmmm.. well that is indeed very strange... could you please post more of your code?